# Pyspark: Uncaught exception in thread heartbeat- receiver-event-loop-thread

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, redis, pyspark

I have a Python spark code as follows. It basically fetches `user_id` from `self.user_RDD` and for that `user_id` it combines the products from  `product_CF` and `product_list`. Then saves into Redis.

```
    for user_id in self.user_RDD.collect():
        product_CF = self.getpreferredProducts(user_id)
        try:
            product_list = json.loads(redis_client.hget('user_products',user_id))
            # combine 2 list
            for product_id in product_list:
                if product_id in product_CF:
                    product_CF.remove(product_id)
            product_list.extend(product_CF)
            r.hset('score',user_id,str(json.dumps(product_list)))
        except Exception as e:
            print e
```

When there is a huge dataset it stops in the middle of the execution and throws the following exception

```
17/04/21 12:10:00 ERROR Utils: Uncaught exception in thread heartbeat-
receiver-event-loop-thread
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator.value(AccumulatorV2.scala:464)
    at org.apache.spark.util.CollectionAccumulator.value(AccumulatorV2.scala:439)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$6$$anonfun$7.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:408)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:893)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterator.foreach(Iterator.scala:1336)
    at scala.collection.IterableLike$class.foreach(IterableLike.scala:72)
    at scala.collection.AbstractIterable.foreach(Iterable.scala:54)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:234)
    at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:104)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:408)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl$$anonfun$6.apply(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:407)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$flatMap$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.flatMap(TraversableLike.scala:241)
    at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.flatMap(ArrayOps.scala:186)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.executorHeartbeatReceived(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:407)
    at org.apache.spark.HeartbeatReceiver$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1$$anon$2$$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(HeartbeatReceiver.scala:129)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryLogNonFatalError(Utils.scala:1283)
    at org.apache.spark.HeartbeatReceiver$$anonfun$receiveAndReply$1$$anon$2.run(HeartbeatReceiver.scala:128)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/04/21 12:10:10 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = Heartbeat(driver,[Lscala.Tuple2;@7b7d4d24,BlockManagerId(driver, 172.31.26.252, 35155, None))] in 1 attempts
org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.executor.heartbeatInterval
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:36)
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:216)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:326)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark_project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:136)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:237)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:63)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(BatchingExecutor.scala:78)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$Batch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:54)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:601)
    at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:106)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:599)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248)
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.org$apache$spark$rpc$netty$NettyRpcEnv$$onFailure$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:205)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:239)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 10 seconds
    ... 8 more
```

Answer (score 0):

It was the issue with the space. I was storing `score` into the local Redis instance. Then I created the AWS Redis and started storing. It solved the problem.